# How can i remove all non text/numbers from this image?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, tesseract

Image link:

[image]

I've tried changing pixels that are not in specific range to white and rest for black using simple code:

```
if (newpix[i] > 179 && newpix[i] < 228 && newpix[i+1] > 177 && newpix[i+1] < 249 && newpix[i+2] > 220 && newpix[i+2] < 256){
newpix[i] = 0;
newpix[i+1] = 0;
newpix[i+2] = 0;
}
else if (newpix[i] > 63 && newpix[i] < 146 && newpix[i+1] > 96 && newpix[i+1] < 182 && newpix[i+2] > 123 && newpix[i+2] < 220)
{
newpix[i] = 0;
newpix[i+1] = 0;
newpix[i+2] = 0;
}
else
{
newpix[i] = 255;
newpix[i+1] = 255;
newpix[i+2] = 255;
}
```

Result:

[image]

That's somehow working, but maybe there is a better way to do this, I would like to leave only nickname, damage, and boss name. Rest is not needed. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can go with a combination of area and color, that should do the job. I have no idea why you would need to do this though.

Comment: Tesseract need to have a black text on white background so it can read it properly. And I need the data from images to make my life easier doing it automatically rather than typing that manually all the time.

Comment: To my eye it seems like the things you want could be isolated by their colors (you would need a little bit of radius on the perfect color centers)

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not easier to scape

https://guardiantalesguides.com/

```js
const container = document.getElementById('raidResults');
const damages = [...container.querySelectorAll('.damage')].map(damage => damage.innerText.split('\n').slice(0, -2))

console.log(damages)
```

```html
<div id="raidResults"> <div class="raidResult" id="result1561"> <div class="damage"> 1,546,610 <div>damage</div> <div style="font-size: 10px; font-style: italic; margin-top: 5px;">716 efficiency score</div> <div>3,360 gear score</div> <div>11 hours ago</div> <div>by <a href="/game/profile/show/3534">Rosemary</a></div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Future+Princess';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Future_Princess.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Future Princess</div> <div class="type Light"><span>Light</span></div> <div>Buff: Hit Points</div> <div><span class="injured">Injured</span> to <span class="downed">Downed</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="gold"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Future_Princess.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Mk.+99';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/316.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Mk. 99</div> <div class="type Light"><span>Light</span></div> <div>Buff: Ranged Atk</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="silver"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/316.png"> <div class="level">78</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Lilith';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/287.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Lilith</div> <div class="type Dark"><span>Dark</span></div> <div>Buff: Melee Atk</div> <div><span class="injured">Injured</span> to <span class="downed">Downed</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="gold"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/287.png"> <div class="level">75</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Future+Knight';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/312.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Future Knight</div> <div class="type Basic"><span>Basic</span></div> <div>Buff: Wep Regen Speed</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="airborne">Airborne</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="gold"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/312.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"> <div>+1</div> </div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="bossImage">vs <a href="/game/raids/viewBoss/48"><img src="/files/site_images/1/262.png"></a> <div class="bossLevel">74</div> </div> </div> <div class="raidResult" id="result1560"> <div class="damage"> 2,575,365 <div>damage</div> <div style="font-size: 10px; font-style: italic; margin-top: 5px;">1,160 efficiency score</div> <div>3,420 gear score</div> <div>11 hours ago</div> <div>by <a href="/game/profile/show/3534">Rosemary</a></div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Beth';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Beth.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Beth</div> <div class="type Dark"><span>Dark</span></div> <div>Buff: Melee Atk</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Beth.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"> <div>+2</div> </div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Bari';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Bari.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Bari</div> <div class="type Earth"><span>Earth</span></div> <div>Buff: Skill Atk</div> <div><span class="injured">Injured</span> to <span class="downed">Downed</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Bari.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"> <div>+2</div> </div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Lifeguard+Yuze';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/302.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Lifeguard Yuze</div> <div class="type Water"><span>Water</span></div> <div>Buff: Wep Regen Speed</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="airborne">Airborne</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/302.png"> <div class="level">75</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Eugene';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Eugene.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Eugene</div> <div class="type Light"><span>Light</span></div> <div>Buff: Melee Atk</div> <div><span class="airborne">Airborne</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Eugene.png"> <div class="level">73</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="bossImage">vs <a href="/game/raids/viewBoss/48"><img src="/files/site_images/1/262.png"></a> <div class="bossLevel">74</div> </div> </div> <div class="raidResult" id="result1559"> <div class="damage"> 2,217,548 <div>damage</div> <div style="font-size: 10px; font-style: italic; margin-top: 5px;">973 efficiency score</div> <div>3,480 gear score</div> <div>11 hours ago</div> <div>by <a href="/game/profile/show/3534">Rosemary</a></div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Beth';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Beth.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Beth</div> <div class="type Dark"><span>Dark</span></div> <div>Buff: Melee Atk</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Beth.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"> <div>+2</div> </div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Bari';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Bari.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Bari</div> <div class="type Earth"><span>Earth</span></div> <div>Buff: Skill Atk</div> <div><span class="injured">Injured</span> to <span class="downed">Downed</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Bari.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"> <div>+2</div> </div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Lifeguard+Yuze';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/302.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Lifeguard Yuze</div> <div class="type Water"><span>Water</span></div> <div>Buff: Wep Regen Speed</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="airborne">Airborne</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/302.png"> <div class="level">75</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Marina';"> <div class="guardianTooltip" style="display: none;"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Marina.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Marina</div> <div class="type Water"><span>Water</span></div> <div>Buff: Hit Points</div> <div><span class="all">All</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="silver"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Marina.png"> <div class="level">73</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="bossImage">vs <a href="/game/raids/viewBoss/48"><img src="/files/site_images/1/262.png"></a> <div class="bossLevel">75</div> </div> </div> <div class="raidResult" id="result1558"> <div class="damage"> 2,289,210 <div>damage</div> <div style="font-size: 10px; font-style: italic; margin-top: 5px;">1,060 efficiency score</div> <div>3,360 gear score</div> <div>11 hours ago</div> <div>by <a href="/game/profile/show/3534">Rosemary</a></div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Lynn';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/314.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Lynn</div> <div class="type Fire"><span>Fire</span></div> <div>Buff: Melee Atk</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="silver"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/314.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"> <div>+2</div> </div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Nari';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Nari.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Nari</div> <div class="type Basic"><span>Basic</span></div> <div>Buff: Ranged Atk</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="airborne">Airborne</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="silver"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Nari.png"> <div class="level">80</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Plitvice';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Plitvice.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Plitvice</div> <div class="type Fire"><span>Fire</span></div> <div>Buff: Fire Damage</div> <div><span class="injured">Injured</span> to <span class="downed">Downed</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="silver"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Plitvice.png"> <div class="level">75</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Kamael';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/369.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Kamael</div> <div class="type Earth"><span>Earth</span></div> <div>Buff: Ranged Atk</div> <div><span class="airborne">Airborne</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="gold"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/369.png"> <div class="level">78</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="bossImage">vs <a href="/game/raids/viewBoss/48"><img src="/files/site_images/1/262.png"></a> <div class="bossLevel">74</div> </div> </div> <div class="raidResult" id="result1557"> <div class="damage"> 2,292,908 <div>damage</div> <div style="font-size: 10px; font-style: italic; margin-top: 5px;">1,062 efficiency score</div> <div>3,360 gear score</div> <div>11 hours ago</div> <div>by <a href="/game/profile/show/3534">Rosemary</a></div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Lynn';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/314.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Lynn</div> <div class="type Fire"><span>Fire</span></div> <div>Buff: Melee Atk</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="silver"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/314.png"> <div class="level">82</div> <div class="weapon"> <div>+2</div> </div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Nari';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Nari.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Nari</div> <div class="type Basic"><span>Basic</span></div> <div>Buff: Ranged Atk</div> <div><span class="downed">Downed</span> to <span class="airborne">Airborne</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="silver"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Nari.png"> <div class="level">80</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Plitvice';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Plitvice.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Plitvice</div> <div class="type Fire"><span>Fire</span></div> <div>Buff: Fire Damage</div> <div><span class="injured">Injured</span> to <span class="downed">Downed</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="silver"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/themes/default/images/art/portraits/Plitvice.png"> <div class="level">75</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="portrait portrait50 " onclick="location.href='/game/guardians/show/Kamael';"> <div class="guardianTooltip"> <img src="/files/site_images/1/369.png"> <div class="topDetails"> <div class="name">Kamael</div> <div class="type Earth"><span>Earth</span></div> <div>Buff: Ranged Atk</div> <div><span class="airborne">Airborne</span> to <span class="injured">Injured</span></div> <div class="meta"> <div class="gold"><span>C</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="gold"><span>A</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>R</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>K</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> <div class="bronze"><span>P</span><i class="fas fa-trophy fa-1x"></i></div> </div> </div> </div> <img src="/files/site_images/1/369.png"> <div class="level">78</div> <div class="weapon"><img src="/themes/default/images/guardian_weapon.png"></div> <div class="starWrapper"> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> <div class="starSmall goldStar"></div> </div> </div> <div class="bossImage">vs <a href="/game/raids/viewBoss/48"><img src="/files/site_images/1/262.png"></a> <div class="bossLevel">74</div> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: But i don't want damage from that site, but only specific guild so I was thinking doing that from images. It would be easier to collect data from guardian tales server I believe I don't have access for getting that data.

Comment: I posted damage as an example.